# AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client finish callback not called

Tags: perl, websocket, anyevent

I am having issue using `AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client`. The send/receive system works well, but I want to use the `on finish` callback to handle connection closure but it is never called.

```
my $client = AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client->new;

$client->connect("ws://...")->cb(sub {
    our $connection = eval { shift->recv };

    if ($@) {
        warn $@;
        return;
    }

    $connection->on(each_message => sub {
        ...
    });

    $connection->on(finish => sub {
        print "Connection finished\n";
    });
});

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

I want the client to try to reconnect when the connection is terminating, but **the `on finish` callback is never called** when I shut down my websocket server.

Any help would be great !

Comment: What web server are you using? You may also try to ask at the GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/plicease/AnyEvent-WebSocket-Client/issues)

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am using Java webserver Payaraa, I am using it for websockets on another use case with javascript websocket client and everything is working fine there.